# Core Data Relationship Designing - Load only desired entity

Tags: xcode, core-data, database-design

I need help in designing the database for my application using Core Data.

Namely:

I have 2 Entites called Verse and Translation.
Verse has one-to-many relationship with translation table.
Translation table contains translations in different languages such as EN,DE,AR.

I know if i load the Verse table then corresponding translations will also be lazy loaded.

But i want to load only desired translation of each Verse. E.g only EN.

Because if i load 1000 Verse and with 5 different Translation (DE,EN,TR,AR,FR) then i have a big amount of data which i want to avoid >> 1000x5 = 5000.

I don‘t want load everytime the translations which i dont need. Only the selected translation.

thank you for any advice.

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found a solution which is exactly what i wanted. I tested and it returns only the desired Translations.

```
- (NSArray *) loadAllVersesByLanguage
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *_managedObjectContext = [self managedObjectContext];
    NSArray *fetchedObjects;
    NSString *turkish = @"TR";//should be parameterized
    NSString *arabic = @"AR";

    NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"languageCode==%@ OR languageCode==%@",turkish,arabic];

    NSFetchRequest *fetch = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Verse"];

    NSError * error = nil;
    fetchedObjects = [_managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetch error:&error];

    if(fetchedObjects != nil && fetchedObjects.count > 0 ){
        for(Verse *verse in fetchedObjects){
            NSSet *verseSet = [verse.translations filteredSetUsingPredicate:pred];
            [verse.translations setSet:verseSet];
        }
        return fetchedObjects;
    }else{
        return nil;
    }

    return nil;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Core data does something called faulting, it should only load data you actually ask for. It might load some metadata for all those objects, but it won't actually load the translation until you ask for it. I would suggest looking into faulting more if you want to know more than that because it seems fairly complex. At least the rest of what faulting is seems complex.

Comment: thank you, your answer led me to `filteredSetUsingPredicate` maybe that can help me too, i am looking at it and faulting. As i said what i want to do is, when i load all Verses from core data that i filter translations and only fetch spesific translation.